# Put Executable jar in SJAS

Tags: client-server, application-server, appserver

I have one executable jar which I want to put in my project's website running on SJAS. I have no clue how to do it. Can anyone help me?

This jar is a J2ME application which I will access (kind of link) from mobile to download the application then it will connect to my server application through web services.

I just want a link which when I open should download .jar file just like we download any software. We used to have one network location to do so but it has been crashed so I am thinking this solution as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I have just added html link in "Index.html" page of website and it is working fine. IDK if this preferred way to handle or not.